# ORACLE Query with ORDER BY and UNION

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have the following Query which works great!

The only thing is that I need the result set in DESC Order and the following ORDER BY Clause that I have appended to the end of my Query generates the following Oracle Error:

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 46 Column: 54

Here is the Query.  Again, this query works. It is just that when I add the following line:

```
FINAL_SEARCH order by FINAL_SEARCH.DOC_HDR_ID desc
```

Everything breaks.

Any ideas?
I believe my ALIAS has something to do with it, but I could be wrong.

Query -

```
    Select * from ( select DISTINCT(DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID), 
    DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID, 
    DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_STAT_CD, 
    DOC_HDR.CRTE_DT, 
    DOC_HDR.TTL, 
    DOC_HDR.APP_DOC_STAT, 
    DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM, 
    DOC1.LBL, DOC1.DOC_HDLR_URL, 
    DOC1.ACTV_IND  
    from KREW_DOC_TYP_T DOC1, KREW_DOC_HDR_T DOC_HDR   
    where DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID IN ( '10000000001' )  and 
        ( DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM =  'PO' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POA' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POC' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM= 'POPH' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM ='PORH' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POR' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'PORT' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POSP' or 
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POV') and 
          DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_STAT_CD!= 'I' and  
          DOC_HDR.DOC_TYP_ID = DOC1.DOC_TYP_ID ) 

    UNION 

    Select DISTINCT DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID, 
            DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID, 
            DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_STAT_CD, 
            DOC_HDR.CRTE_DT, 
            DOC_HDR.TTL, 
            DOC_HDR.APP_DOC_STAT, 
            DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM, 
            DOC1.LBL, 
            DOC1.DOC_HDLR_URL, 
            DOC1.ACTV_IND 
     FROM KREW_DOC_TYP_T DOC1, 
   KREW_DOC_HDR_T DOC_HDR 
   WHERE DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'PO' AND CAST(DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID AS VARCHAR(14)) = ANY ( 
      Select PPT.FDOC_NBR 
      FROM PUR_PO_T PPT, PL_PURCHASE_LOG_PO_T PPL 
      WHERE PPT.AP_PUR_DOC_LNK_ID = ANY ( 
         Select PRT.AP_PUR_DOC_LNK_ID 
         FROM PUR_REQS_T PRT, 
              KREW_DOC_HDR_T DOC_HDR 
         WHERE CAST(DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID AS VARCHAR(14)) = PRT.FDOC_NBR AND 
           DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID IN ( '10000000001' ) )) FINAL_SEARCH order by FINAL_SEARCH.DOC_HDR_ID desc;
```

UPDATE - I removed the ALIAS and placed the 'ORDER BY' Statement after both queries and it worked in SQL Developer; however, when I execute this Query through the Web Application that generates this query using Java, I get a ORACLE ERROR about an INVALID SYMBOL.
The invalid symbol is a semi-colon that use to terminate the 1st ORDER BY Statement.  It won't work otherwise in SQL Developer, but apparently when I execute that same statement that I generate through the Web App - it fails.

Comment: Does it work from the web app without the semicolon?

Comment: I get the following if I remove the semi-colon: Error received trying to execute search: DataAccessException: ConnectionCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: You didn't encase your code with proper ( )'s. Answer is below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count your brackets - the two queries being unioned should be in one bracket - then your alias and SELECT * FROM will work.

```
SELECT *
    FROM ( (SELECT DISTINCT (doc_hdr.doc_hdr_id),
                            doc_hdr.initr_prncpl_id,
                            doc_hdr.doc_hdr_stat_cd,
                            doc_hdr.crte_dt,
                            doc_hdr.ttl,
                            doc_hdr.app_doc_stat,
                            doc1.doc_typ_nm,
                            doc1.lbl,
                            doc1.doc_hdlr_url,
                            doc1.actv_ind
              FROM krew_doc_typ_t doc1, krew_doc_hdr_t doc_hdr
             WHERE doc_hdr.initr_prncpl_id IN ('10000000001')
               AND (doc1.doc_typ_nm = 'PO'
                 OR doc1.doc_typ_nm = 'POA'
                 OR doc1.doc_typ_nm = 'POC'
                 OR doc1.doc_typ_nm = 'POPH'
                 OR doc1.doc_typ_nm = 'PORH'
                 OR doc1.doc_typ_nm = 'POR'
                 OR doc1.doc_typ_nm = 'PORT'
                 OR doc1.doc_typ_nm = 'POSP'
                 OR doc1.doc_typ_nm = 'POV')
               AND doc_hdr.doc_hdr_stat_cd != 'I'
               AND doc_hdr.doc_typ_id = doc1.doc_typ_id)
          UNION
          SELECT DISTINCT doc_hdr.doc_hdr_id,
                          doc_hdr.initr_prncpl_id,
                          doc_hdr.doc_hdr_stat_cd,
                          doc_hdr.crte_dt,
                          doc_hdr.ttl,
                          doc_hdr.app_doc_stat,
                          doc1.doc_typ_nm,
                          doc1.lbl,
                          doc1.doc_hdlr_url,
                          doc1.actv_ind
            FROM krew_doc_typ_t doc1, krew_doc_hdr_t doc_hdr
           WHERE doc1.doc_typ_nm = 'PO'
             AND CAST (doc_hdr.doc_hdr_id AS VARCHAR (14)) =
                     ANY (SELECT ppt.fdoc_nbr
                            FROM pur_po_t ppt, pl_purchase_log_po_t ppl
                           WHERE ppt.ap_pur_doc_lnk_id =
                                     ANY (SELECT prt.ap_pur_doc_lnk_id
                                            FROM pur_reqs_t prt,
                                                 krew_doc_hdr_t doc_hdr
                                           WHERE CAST (
                                                     doc_hdr.doc_hdr_id AS VARCHAR (14)
                                                 ) = prt.fdoc_nbr
                                             AND doc_hdr.initr_prncpl_id IN
                                                         ('10000000001'))))
         final_search
ORDER BY final_search.doc_hdr_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using an extra bracket ')'

```
 Select * from ( select DISTINCT(DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID), 
    DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID, 
    DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_STAT_CD, 
    DOC_HDR.CRTE_DT, 
    DOC_HDR.TTL, 
    DOC_HDR.APP_DOC_STAT, 
    DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM, 
    DOC1.LBL, DOC1.DOC_HDLR_URL, 
    DOC1.ACTV_IND  
    from KREW_DOC_TYP_T DOC1, KREW_DOC_HDR_T DOC_HDR   
    where DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID IN ( '10000000001' )  and 
        ( DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM =  'PO' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POA' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POC' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM= 'POPH' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM ='PORH' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POR' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'PORT' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POSP' or 
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POV') and 
          DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_STAT_CD!= 'I' and  
          DOC_HDR.DOC_TYP_ID = DOC1.DOC_TYP_ID  

    UNION 

    Select DISTINCT DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID, 
            DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID, 
            DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_STAT_CD, 
            DOC_HDR.CRTE_DT, 
            DOC_HDR.TTL, 
            DOC_HDR.APP_DOC_STAT, 
            DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM, 
            DOC1.LBL, 
            DOC1.DOC_HDLR_URL, 
            DOC1.ACTV_IND 
     FROM KREW_DOC_TYP_T DOC1, 
   KREW_DOC_HDR_T DOC_HDR 
   WHERE DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'PO' AND CAST(DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID AS VARCHAR(14)) = ANY ( 
      Select PPT.FDOC_NBR 
      FROM PUR_PO_T PPT, PL_PURCHASE_LOG_PO_T PPL 
      WHERE PPT.AP_PUR_DOC_LNK_ID = ANY ( 
         Select PRT.AP_PUR_DOC_LNK_ID 
         FROM PUR_REQS_T PRT, 
              KREW_DOC_HDR_T DOC_HDR 
         WHERE CAST(DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID AS VARCHAR(14)) = PRT.FDOC_NBR AND 
           DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID IN ( '10000000001' ) ))) FINAL_SEARCH order by FINAL_SEARCH.DOC_HDR_ID desc;
```

remove the last bracket form first where condition, and try.
Also add one more bracket at the end `) FINAL_SEARCH order by`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot some parentheses:

```sql
Select * from ( select DISTINCT(DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID), 
    DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID, 
    DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_STAT_CD, 
    DOC_HDR.CRTE_DT, 
    DOC_HDR.TTL, 
    DOC_HDR.APP_DOC_STAT, 
    DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM, 
    DOC1.LBL, DOC1.DOC_HDLR_URL, 
    DOC1.ACTV_IND  
    from KREW_DOC_TYP_T DOC1, KREW_DOC_HDR_T DOC_HDR   
    where DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID IN ( '10000000001' )  and 
        ( DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM =  'PO' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POA' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POC' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM= 'POPH' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM ='PORH' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POR' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'PORT' or  
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POSP' or 
          DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'POV') and 
          DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_STAT_CD!= 'I' and  
          DOC_HDR.DOC_TYP_ID = DOC1.DOC_TYP_ID ) 

    UNION 

    (Select DISTINCT DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID, 
            DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID, 
            DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_STAT_CD, 
            DOC_HDR.CRTE_DT, 
            DOC_HDR.TTL, 
            DOC_HDR.APP_DOC_STAT, 
            DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM, 
            DOC1.LBL, 
            DOC1.DOC_HDLR_URL, 
            DOC1.ACTV_IND 
     FROM KREW_DOC_TYP_T DOC1, 
   KREW_DOC_HDR_T DOC_HDR 
   WHERE DOC1.DOC_TYP_NM = 'PO' AND CAST(DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID AS VARCHAR(14)) = ANY ( 
      Select PPT.FDOC_NBR 
      FROM PUR_PO_T PPT, PL_PURCHASE_LOG_PO_T PPL 
      WHERE PPT.AP_PUR_DOC_LNK_ID = ANY ( 
         Select PRT.AP_PUR_DOC_LNK_ID 
         FROM PUR_REQS_T PRT, 
              KREW_DOC_HDR_T DOC_HDR 
         WHERE CAST(DOC_HDR.DOC_HDR_ID AS VARCHAR(14)) = PRT.FDOC_NBR AND 
           DOC_HDR.INITR_PRNCPL_ID IN ( '10000000001' ) ))) FINAL_SEARCH order by FINAL_SEARCH.DOC_HDR_ID desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove ";" symbol in web apps for filling datasetd/datatables.

Also you can use column order as alias in order by block such as:

Select .....
Order by 1 asc, 4 desc