# Oracle: Order by Union returning ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, union, ora-00933

I have an issue with using Oracle's union and order by clauses together.

I have two complex queries (with sub queries in them) having an order by clause for each of them. I need to union the output of both and return the result. When I run it, I am getting the error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

But it works when I comment out the order by clauses in both of them.

To test this, I created a simple query as simple as shown below

```
select * from employee where employee_id=2 order by name
union
select * from employee where employee_id=3 order by name;
```

Even this gave the same error when ran with order by clauses but runs well when I commentout the order by clauses.

I tried searching forums, but I could not get solution for the exact problem. I found one at [ORACLE Query with ORDER BY and UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889518/oracle-query-with-order-by-and-union) but As my queries are already too complecated because of subqueries and joins between too many tables, I dont want to implement this.

Can someone help me on fixing the root cause of the issue.

Comment: You can only have one `order by` at the very end of any union of sets.

Comment: check my answer again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code:

```
select  e1.name name /* e1.* */
  from employee e1
 where employee_id = 2
union
select 
  e2.name name /* e2.* */
  from employee e2
 where employee_id = 3
 order by name;
```

if you want to order the result of first query then to order the result the second query so you can do like this:

```
select 1 query, e1.name name /* e1.* */
  from employee e1
 where employee_id = 2
union
select 
 2 query, e2.name name /* e2.* */
  from employee e2
 where employee_id = 3
 order by query, name;
```

Comment: I already tried this. This did not work. it gives Error: ORA-00904: "column name used in order by clause": invalid identifier

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick help. I modified your fist suggestion a little bit and it worked for me. I just changed the column alias to name1 both in the select and in the order by clauses.

Answer (score 4):

You can have only one `ORDER BY` when combining multiple queries, on the last statement. The `ORDER BY` clause acts on the *entire* set.

See the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm):

> You cannot specify the order_by_clause in the subquery of these operators.

Answer (score 3):

If you want order by in each query you must wrap it in other select as a subquery:

```
select * from (select * from employee where employee_id=2 order by name)
union
select * from (select * from employee where employee_id=3 order by name);
```